# How to run Arduino sketch automatically from flash drive?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, usb-drive

I will be using an Arduino Gemma board, and I would like it to run a program directly from a USB drive as soon as it is plugged in. I am pretty new to Arduino, I mainly just know Raspberry Pi and Python, so anything would help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  The ATtiny85 does not act as a USB host and so cannot host a USB flash drive as a "hard disk."  The micro-USB onboard is strictly a power and programming interface.